# Discord-buttons are not working in discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js, discord-buttons

I want to make an embed with three buttons in discord.js v12. When I am trying to send the message it returns me `[object Object]`. What I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
const app = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("my embed here")

let staff = new disbut.MessageButton()
.setStyle('gray')
.setLabel('STAFF')
.setURL('url')
                
let ellas = new MessageButton()
.setStyle('gray')
.setLabel('‍♀️POLICE')
.setURL('url')

let ekav = new disbut.MessageButton()
.setStyle('gray')
.setLabel('EKAB')
.setURL('url')

message.channel.send(app, {
    buttons: [staff, ellas, ekav]
});
```

Comment: I advise you update to v13, so you can use the built-in MessageButtons

Comment: @MrMythical I know that v13 is better but for now I'm working on v12.

Comment: Try this ```message.channel.send({components: [staff, ellas, ekav]});```